# Database Queries don't run but neither are the SQL Exceptions Thrown

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I am running C# .NET code where I need to test certain values that have been entered in a web page form and then passed to the server. The server then uses those values
in a query string to return a value. I encase these query instructions within a try-catch block in order to trace any Sql exceptions.
The problem is this:
Once the application has started, the connection string is set, and the query is run, I don't get a stack trace from the catch block's SQL Exception but instead
I just get a blank/empty value within the method that ran the query.  The method will return a Boolean variable to indicate if there was any value read from the query and if so it returns true however it always returns false which should not happen because I have checked the query string that it builds by pasting it into  MS SQL 2008's  Query Console and running it. The results from running the pasted SQL instruction test  does produce non-null data from the query. Thank much for your help.

I'm running VS2003 with IIS 6.0 and using MS SQL 2008 Enterprise Studio

## Here is the code segment for the web.config and C# code. Thanks much for your help.:

```
<system.web>

    <!--  DYNAMIC DEBUG COMPILATION
          Set compilation debug="true" to enable ASPX debugging.  Otherwise, setting this value to
          false will improve runtime performance of this application. 
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging symbols (.pdb information)
          into the compiled page. Because this creates a larger file that executes
          more slowly, you should set this value to true only when debugging and to
          false at all other times. For more information, refer to the documentation about
          debugging ASP.NET files.
    -->
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
```

====================

```
//This method takes one string and returns either country name or Canadian state as a string, according to query.
    private string candStateCountryCheck(string strQuery)
    {
        string strStateCountry = "";
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader sdr = null;

        try
        {   
            string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OLEDBConnectionString"];
            con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(sdr.Read())
            {
                strStateCountry = sdr.GetString(0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "ERROR:" + exc.Message;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (sdr != null)
                sdr.Close();
            if (cmd != null)
                cmd.Dispose();
            if (con != null)
                con.Close();
        }
        return strStateCountry;
    }
```

Comment: If you replace `sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(sdr.Read())
            {
                strStateCountry = sdr.GetString(0);
            }` with `strStateCountry = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`, what happens?

Comment: Try running the MS Sql profile and see what the sql thinks the code is doing.

Comment: Methods that accept sql code as strings with no provision for parameters are an evil anti-pattern.

Comment: I know this is a fairly standard comment on ADO.Net questions but please consider wrapping those Command, Connection etc objects in Using statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I think your should use `ExecuteScaler` for single result queries.  I also encourage you to use parameterized queries:

```
 while (sdr.Read())
 {
     strStateCountry = sdr.GetString(0);
 }
```

[`ExucuteScaler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) example:

```
    try
    {
        string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OLEDBConnectionString"];
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
             con.Open();
             using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con))
             {
                 strStateCountry = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of if, you're doing a while in order to set the same variable multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to avoid anything here that won't work with VS2003, but it's gonna be hard... VS2003 is getting pretty old now, and you know that the express edition of VS2010 is available for free, right?

Also, this is a re-write of your code to show a better example of how it *should* look, if it were using a fictional database. You did not share any of your database structure, any example data, or what a query might look like, so that's the best we can do for now:

```
private string candStateCountryCheck(string toTest)
{
    string sql = "SELECT countryStateName FROM SomeTable WHERE ItemKey LIKE @Query + '%';";

    try
    {   
        string strConnection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OLEDBConnectionString"];

        con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Query", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = toTest;

        con.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = "ERROR:" + exc.Message;
    }
    finally 
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You **NEVER** want to write methods that expect fully-formed sql code as arguments.